# How Amazon Elastic Container Service is Different from Kubernetes when we want to deploy our dockerize application over it?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices, amazon-ecs

I am planning to start my project but a bit confuse between choosing Amazon ECS and Kubernetes perhaps I am really a beginner  with Micro-services architecture.

I would really appreciate if someone can show some path for deploying my docker container on a fast easier to handle platform.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a list of differences from the top of my head:

AWS ECS / Kubernetes:

- Proprietary AWS implementation / Open source solution
- Runs on AWS / Supported by most cloud providers and on premise
- Task Definitions / PODs have different features
- Runs on your EC2 machines or allows for serverless with Fargate (in beta) / Runs on any cluster of (physical/virtual/cloud) machines running the kubernetes controller.
- Support for AWS VPCs /  Support for multiple networking models

I would also argue that kubernetes has a slightly steeper learning curve but ultimately provides more freedom and is probably a safer bet for the future given the wide adoption.

Features supported in both systems:

- Horizontal application scalability
- Cluster Scalability
- Load Balancing
- Rolling upgrades
- Logging (with additional logging systems)
- Container Health Checks
- APIs

Amazon has bowed to customer pressure and currently has a managed kubernetes support in beta (EKS).

*edit: EKS is released now - but with an upcharge for the cluster controller nodes, as compared to google GKE for example.

Here is one [article](https://platform9.com/blog/compare-kubernetes-vs-ecs/) about the topic.